# Proving that for a martingale $X_n$ and stopping time $N$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{N \wedge n} = X_N$

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal{F}_n$. We define the stopped martingale as $X_{N \wedge n}$, where $N$ is a stopping time. It is well known that $(X_{N \wedge n})_{n \geq 1}$ itself forms a martingale. If we further assume that $N < \infty$ almost surely, it is also known that:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{N \wedge n} = X_N
$$
Heuristically, this makes perfect sense. However, I have no idea how to prove this rigorously. A brief search online does not seem to yield any results.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming that $P(N <\infty)=1$. Otherwise $X_N$ may not be defined.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. It has been included now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X_{N \wedge n}=X_N$ whenever $n \geq N$, hence $X_{N \wedge n} \to X_N$. You don't require any probability theory for this.

Comment: I agree that $X_{N \wedge n} = X_N$ if $n \geq N$. How does one write out rigorously that this implies $X_{N \wedge n} \to X_N$?

Comment: $|X_{N \wedge n}-X_N|=0 <\epsilon$ for $n >N$. That is the proof.

Comment: Right, I missed that. Thanks.